# I can not deal with the AsyncTask

Tags: android, android-asynctask

I can not understand whether I ever made?
I have a class which takes a reference to the input and the output gives me an object Document(Jsoup library). I then in the main stream parsing the object and set on the form data. at the beginning of the work I show ProgressDialog and at the end of it I'm. But everything works is unclear. I run a process asinktask starts and the form freezes (about a second). Sidebar does not have time to close. Then form droops ProgressDialog appears for a split second and closed. The data are mounted on the form. Everything is very fast, but what form freezes and ProgressDialog started only after it droops worries me.

```
public class MyAsincTask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, Document> {
    private Document document;
    private ProgressDialog progressDialog;

    public MyAsincTask(Context context) {
        progressDialog = MyProgress.getProgressDialog(context);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        progressDialog.show();
        super.onPreExecute();
    }

    @Override
    protected Document doInBackground(String... params) {
        try {
            document = Jsoup.connect(params[0]).get();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return document;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Document document) {
        progressDialog.cancel();
        super.onPostExecute(document);
    }
}
```

and

```
 public void setData(){
            MyAsincTask task = new MyAsincTask(getActivity());
            task.execute(link);
            try {
                document = task.get();
            } catch (InterruptedException | ExecutionException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            guests = new ArrayList<>();
            Elements elementsUserId = document.select("guest_id");
            Elements elementsNumbers = document.select("room");
            Elements elementsNames = document.select("name");
            ...


            for (int i = 0; i < elementsNumbers.size(); i++) {
                GuestBean guest = new GuestBean();
                guest.setUserId(elementsUserId.get(i).ownText());
                guest.setRoom(elementsNumbers.get(i).ownText());
                guest.setName(elementsNames.get(i).ownText());
                ...
                guests.add(guest);
                count++;
            }
            GuestsListAdapter adapter = new GuestsListAdapter(getActivity(), guests);
            list.setAdapter(adapter);
        }
```

Comment: `run a process as in task starts and the form freezes (about a second)` because of `document = task.get();`. line see [AsyncTask.get()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html#get%28long,%20java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit%29) for more detail.

Comment: I know that hangs therefore. the question is whether it is right? task.get() waits when AsyncTask finish work. and while waiting for the main thread hangs. I need to at this time spinning my progressBar.it can?

Comment: `I need to at this time spinning my progressBar` to do same use `onPostExecute` for performing options on result of `doInBackground`. see [Android AsyncTask ListView – JSON](http://www.javacodegeeks.com/2013/06/android-asynctask-listview-json.html) example for more help

Comment: @PavelPetrashov : NEVER use the `get()` method of `AsyncTask`. I really wish the Android devs would remove it as it only causes confusion for people who don't understand the implications. Move the code in your setData method into `onPostExecute(..)` instead.

Comment: @Squonk I did so. but I wanted to use a single class AsyncTask for all fragments.

Comment: @PavelPetrashov : Using a stand-alone `AsyncTask` with different app components (e.g., Activities or Fragments) gets complicated and is potentially unsafe when used by an `Activity` if the device is rotated. If I need to use an `AsyncTask` I usually make it an inner class of a base `Activity` or base `Fragment` and then extend those classes. Alternatively, I prefer to use an `IntentService` for most asynchronous operations.

Answer (score 0):

AS  `@ρяσѕρєя K` said above the problem is `document = task.get();`, Here the thread will get blocked.You can done this by using an `Interface` like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12575068/how-to-get-the-result-of-onpostexecute-to-main-activity-because-asynctask-is-a).

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution

```
 public void setData() {
        new MyAsincTask(getActivity()){
            @Override
            protected void onPreExecute() {
                super.onPreExecute();
            }

            @Override
            protected void onPostExecute(Document document) {
                super.onPostExecute(document);
                Elements elementsDate = document.select("date");
                Elements elementsName = document.select("name");
                Elements elementsSumm = document.select("summa");

                for (int i = 0; i < elementsName.size(); i++) {
                    FolioBean folioBean = new FolioBean();
                    folioBean.setDate(elementsDate.get(i).ownText());
                    folioBean.setName(elementsName.get(i).ownText());
                    folioBean.setSumm(elementsSumm.get(i).ownText());
                    folioBeans.add(folioBean);
                }
                TableRow.LayoutParams row_params = new TableRow.LayoutParams(TableRow.LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT, TableRow.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, 20f);
                TableRow.LayoutParams row_params2 = new TableRow.LayoutParams(TableRow.LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT, TableRow.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, 30f);

                for (FolioBean folioBean : folioBeans) {
                    TableRow tableRow = new TableRow(getActivity());
                    TextView data = new TextView(getActivity());
                    TextView name = new TextView(getActivity());
                    TextView summ = new TextView(getActivity());
                    data.setTextSize(10);
                    name.setTextSize(10);
                    summ.setTextSize(10);
                    name.setTextColor(Color.BLACK);
                    summ.setTextColor(Color.BLACK);
                    data.setTextColor(Color.BLACK);
                    data.setText(" " + folioBean.getDate());
                    name.setText(" " + folioBean.getName() + " ");
                    summ.setText(folioBean.getSumm() + " ");
                    tableRow.addView(data, row_params2);
                    tableRow.addView(name, row_params2);
                    tableRow.addView(summ, row_params);
                    tableFolio.addView(tableRow);
                }
            }
        }.execute(link);
    }
```